# PostgreSQL point type in Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

**I want** to use the **point** type which there's in PostgreSQL. I've done:

```
rails g model Test point:point
```

The resulting migration is:

```
class CreateTests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tests do |t|
      t.point :point

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

The result is:

```
    ==  CreateTests: migrating ====================================================
    -- create_table(:tests)
    rake aborted!
    An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

    undefined method `point' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x000000038991a0>/home/i/Dropbox/programming/ruby/rails_pg_for_tests/db/migrate/20140306151700_create_tests.rb:4:in `block in change'
    /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:184:in `create_table'
    /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `block in method_missing'
    /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `block in say_with_time'
...
```

May be I need to install PostGIS, but I don't understand what for, if I have point type in PostgreSQL. And I only need to store latitude and longitude without any other options.

How can I use this point type or what is better to use in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Just because PostgreSQL has a point type, doesn't mean ActiveRecord supports it.

Comment: the `point` type is from PostgreSQL, and has nothing to do with PostGIS's `geometry` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive `undefined method 'point' for #<ActiveRecord:...` error on migration code

```
t.point :point
```

because `point` method does not exist in `ActiveRecord`.

`ActiveRecord` natively supports following `data types`,

```
 :primary_key, :string, :text, :integer, :float, :decimal, :datetime, :timestamp, 
 :time, :date, :binary, :boolean
```

See the [official documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) of ActiveRecord for the same.

As suggested by @bridiver, you could choose to specify a type other than the *supported* datatypes of ActiveRecord(as listed above) with `t.column :point, 'point'` BUT as quoted in `ActiveRecord` documentation

> this will not be database agnostic and should usually be avoided.

**UPDATE**

I would recommend utilizing the benefits of `activerecord-postgis-adapter gem`, as suggested by @euricovidal. It is a geospatial extension for pgsql and it acts as a wrapper around the PostGIS query functions and allows you to write geo-aware migrations. 
It will allow you to create a `point` type and using this your current syntax should work.

Refer [PostGIS ActiveRecord Adapter: Creating Spatial Tables](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter#creating-spatial-tables) for example. You would also need to update the `adapter` to `postgis` in the `database.yml` file for this to work.

Comment: Please add a comment to describe why you are down voting the answer so I can improve the answer, don't just down vote.

Comment: I down voted it because it's wrong. You can specify arbitrary types by using column as I've outlined below.

Comment: @bridiver Thank you for that point. I have added explanation in my answer.

Comment: using postgis would have the same caveat that it will not be database agnostic

Comment: @bridiver When it is a database specific thing, its ofcourse going to be database agnostic in this case for both the scenarios. It remains as a matter of preference for OP(taking into account maintainability and usability concerns) whether he wishes to pick something that is not primarily supported by the gem in use or he uses an extension of the gem which is specifically crafted for the requirement.

Comment: regardless the caveat applies to both, so why single out one of them as if it doesn't apply to the other? Neither solution is database agnostic.

Answer (score 8):

You can specify the data type as a string

```
t.column 'point', 'point'
```

Comment: The first `point` is the column name, the second one is the column type.

Answer (score 6):

Rails have support for point for several years. The test cases have been there since rails 4.2 beta.

If you are using rails 4.2 or later. you should not get that error. I have not tested it on 4.2 beta yet. I only test it on rails 5.2 and it works without any additional gem.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/24adc20ace69ec0fcf317e0a8d91d112478ba015/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/point.rb

Usage:

Migration

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.point   :coordinate
    end
  end
end
```

Create a new record

```
Address.create coordinate: ActiveRecord::Point.new(1, 1)
```

Comment: That's very welcoming update, especially when writing bleeding edge Rails 6 and `activerecord-postgis-adapter` gem is not available yet.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using activerecord-postgis-adapter you need change adapter on database.yml to postgis.

https://github.com/dazuma/activerecord-postgis-adapter#installation-and-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to edit your `config\database.yml` to reference **postgis** as your database *adapter*

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: learning_rails
  username: brentpayne
  password:
```

You might also want to edit your migration to specify the `:point` as `geographic` so you can calculate distances.

```
  t.point :point, :geographic => true
```

But the error you are having is identical to mine when I left my *adapter* set to **postgresql**.  Changing it to **postgis** fixed my issues.

Reference: https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter#installation-and-configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you install `georuby` the point datatype becomes available.

Gemfile

```
gem 'pg'
gem 'georuby'
```

In a migration

```
def change
  create_table :space_table do |t|
    t.point :location
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

You can save a point with `model_object.location = [-33.233, 123.123]`